# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Community speaks! On a side note, this is kind of hard, because some of the questions we've asked aren't exactly on Google. . .

Comment: Yeah, this is going to be an interesting site self-eval.

Comment: FYI, [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/lets-get-critical-nov-2014-site-self-evaluation)'s what happened on another beta site with a lot of non-Googlable content.

Comment: just 36 participants ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [That's no Moon: Planet-sized Plants Possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/thats-no-moon-planet-sized-plants-possible)

**Net Score: 25** (Excellent: 25, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Making a planet habitable for humanoids: The planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/making-a-planet-habitable-for-humanoids-the-planet)

**Net Score: 23** (Excellent: 24, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can my accidental time travelers determine the year using star/stars?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9707/how-can-my-accidental-time-travelers-determine-the-year-using-star-stars)

**Net Score: 22** (Excellent: 24, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What sort of problems might occur if every human gained extra muscle mass?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/what-sort-of-problems-might-occur-if-every-human-gained-extra-muscle-mass)

**Net Score: 22** (Excellent: 23, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Weaponising Local Air Pressure](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/weaponising-local-air-pressure)

**Net Score: 21** (Excellent: 21, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cohabitation with large creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9856/cohabitation-with-large-creatures)

**Net Score: 19** (Excellent: 21, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Conditions needed for a Fractured Moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/conditions-needed-for-a-fractured-moon)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What if Jupiter's rotational period was equal to that of the Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10044/what-if-jupiters-rotational-period-was-equal-to-that-of-the-earth)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Of Augmentation and Androidisation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10405/of-augmentation-and-androidisation)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

- [Post-singularity economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10327/post-singularity-economy)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 21, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

Comment: Well we thought we did good.